# Prevent Jupyter Notebook from merging markdown cells

Tags: python, pdf, jupyter-notebook, latex

Whenever I export my Jupyter notebook to a PDF via LaTeX, it seems to merge the markdown cells adjacent to one another into the same line.

**Example**

In Jupyter notebook:
[image]
[image]

In exported PDF:
[image]

How do I prevent the merging of these markdown cells?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix this issue by inserting cells between adjacent markdown cells and filling them up with `<br>` tags.

Like so:

```
*****************************
*      Markdown cell 1      *
*****************************

*****************************
*   <br> (1 or more times)  *
*****************************

*****************************
*      Markdown cell 2      *
*****************************
```

***Note:*** This won't work if you insert the `<br>` tags at the end of the first markdown cell or at the beginning of the second one. The `<br>` tags need to be in their own separate cell.